# How to make static Dynamic pages?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mybb

In MyBB forums you must have seen that all those threads are stoed as forum.com/Thread-Name-of-the-thread
So now this is static right ?

So now i have a site which has

blog.com/search.php?=SEARCHED+TEXT

So now how do i save this search so that Google can find out this page on my site ?

Indirectly what i mean to say is how i can i make

blog.com/SEARCHED+TEXT.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"So now this is static right?" No. Just because the URL doesn't end in .php or similar doesn't mean it's static. It's time for you to learn the wonders of mod_rewrite:

http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite

Answer (score 2):

Your first example isn't static at all. It's just using a tool to route the request based on the URL.

All you need to get the same functionality is to investigate [URL Routing in PHP](http://www.phpaddiction.com/tags/axial/url-routing-with-php-part-one/) and implement it in your application as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want Google to index this search page you have to tell Google it exists, either through a [Sitemap](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=google+sitemap+php) or by putting a link on your site that Google can crawl. Google did fill in forms in the past, but I am not sure if they still do and afaik, they only did on a selected few sites.

To make the search static, you have to render the page once and store it in a file. Whether you do that manually by simply calling up the file in your browser and then saving it or by means of a [Caching System](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=caching+php) is up to you.

Comment: Yes,How do i store the file ?

Comment: @5416339 have a look at the linked questions and answers for Caching System. But like others already pointed out, you might want to get a clear idea whether that is really what you are looking for.